How to create a unit test for React-Native-Signature-Canvas or mock a method
I wrote a unit test on react-native-signature-canvas, of which only 4/5 succeeded. My last test case "calls readSignatureMock when the TouchableOpacity button is pressed" is failing because I am unable to properly mimic the method. Can someone please help me figure out how to properly mimic the method?
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)  
Expected number of calls: 1  
Received number of calls: 0 

This is the component code
import { DCIcon, DCTypography, useTheme } from '@daxko/daxko-mobile-ui';
import React, { forwardRef, useCallback, useImperativeHandle, useMemo, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import SignatureScreen, { SignatureViewRef } from 'react-native-signature-canvas';

import getLocaleString from '@/utils/locale/getTranslations';

export interface SignaturePadProps {
  handleSignature: (signature: string) => void;
}

export interface SignaturePadRef {
  handleReadSignature: () => void;
}

const useStyles = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();

  return useMemo(
    () =>
      StyleSheet.create({
        signaturePadWrapper: {
          backgroundColor: theme.colors.usages.neutralColors.highlight,
          paddingTop: theme.spacing[16],
          height: 180,
        },
        signaturePadLabel: {
          paddingHorizontal: theme.spacing[16],
        },
        signaturePad: {
          minHeight: 140,
          height: 140,
          width: '100%',
          borderBottomWidth: 1,
          borderBottomColor: theme.colors.usages.neutralColors.borderColor,
          position: 'relative',
        },
        signaturePadClearButton: {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          height: theme.spacing[40],
          width: theme.spacing[40],
          position: 'absolute',
          top: theme.spacing[4],
          right: 0,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        },
        signaturePadClearButtonIcon: {
          color: theme.colors.usages.neutralColors.disabledText,
        },
      }),
    [theme],
  );
};

const SignaturePad = forwardRef<SignaturePadRef, SignaturePadProps>(({ handleSignature }, ref) => {
  const styles = useStyles();
  const canvasRef = useRef<SignatureViewRef>(null);
  const [isTouched, setIsTouched] = useState(false);

  const SignatureScreenWebStyle = useMemo(
    () => `.m-signature-pad {box-shadow: none; border: none; border-radius: 0;} 
              .m-signature-pad--body {border: none;}
              .m-signature-pad--footer {display: none; margin: 0px;}
              `,
    [],
  );

  const onTouchStart = useCallback(() => {
    if (!isTouched) {
      setIsTouched(true);
    }
  }, [isTouched]);

  const handleCanvasClear = useCallback(() => {
    canvasRef?.current?.clearSignature();
    setIsTouched(false);
  }, []);

  const handleCanvasData = useCallback(
    (signature: string) => {
      handleSignature(signature);
    },
    [handleSignature],
  );

  const handleReadSignature = useCallback(() => {
    canvasRef?.current?.readSignature();
  }, []);

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    handleReadSignature,
  }));

  return (
    <View style={styles.signaturePadWrapper}>
      <DCTypography.LabelText style={styles.signaturePadLabel}>
        {getLocaleString('unsignedDocumentModal.signaturePadLabel')}
      </DCTypography.LabelText>
      <SignatureScreen
        ref={canvasRef}
        onBegin={onTouchStart}
        onOK={handleCanvasData}
        webStyle={SignatureScreenWebStyle}
        style={styles.signaturePad}
        dotSize={2}
        maxWidth={1}
        minWidth={1}
      />
      {isTouched && (
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.signaturePadClearButton}
          onPress={handleCanvasClear}
          testID="signature-clear-button"
        >
          <DCIcon icon="circle-xmark-solid" style={styles.signaturePadClearButtonIcon} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
    </View>
  );
});

export default SignaturePad;

Here is the Test case
import { render, fireEvent, act } from '@testing-library/react-native';
import React, { ComponentProps } from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import SignatureScreen from 'react-native-signature-canvas';

import SignaturePad from './SignaturePad';

function MockSignatureScreen(props: ComponentProps<typeof SignatureScreen>, ref: React.Ref<View>) {
  const signatureScreenProps = {
    ...props,
    ref,
    testID: 'signature-screen',
    readSignature: jest.fn(),
  };
  return React.createElement('SignatureScreen', signatureScreenProps);
}
jest.mock('react-native-signature-canvas', () => {
  const { forwardRef } = jest.requireActual('react');

  return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: forwardRef((props: ComponentProps<typeof SignatureScreen>, ref: React.Ref<View>) =>
      MockSignatureScreen(props, ref),
    ),
  };
});

describe('SignaturePad Component', () => {
  const mockHandleSignature = jest.fn();
  let componentRef: React.RefObject<any>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    componentRef = React.createRef();
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it('renders correctly', () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<SignaturePad handleSignature={mockHandleSignature} ref={componentRef} />);
    expect(getByText('unsignedDocumentModal.signaturePadLabel')).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('handles signature touch and clear', () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<SignaturePad handleSignature={mockHandleSignature} ref={componentRef} />);
    act(() => {
      fireEvent(getByTestId('signature-screen'), 'onBegin');
    });
    expect(getByTestId('signature-clear-button')).toBeTruthy();
    act(() => {
      fireEvent.press(getByTestId('signature-clear-button'));
    });
  });

  it('calls handleSignature when signature is complete', () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<SignaturePad handleSignature={mockHandleSignature} ref={componentRef} />);
    const signatureScreen = getByTestId('signature-screen');
    act(() => {
      fireEvent(signatureScreen, 'onOK', 'test-signature-data');
    });
    expect(mockHandleSignature).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test-signature-data');
  });

  it('updates isTouched state when onTouchStart is triggered', () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<SignaturePad handleSignature={mockHandleSignature} ref={componentRef} />);
    act(() => {
      fireEvent(getByTestId('signature-screen'), 'onBegin');
    });
    expect(getByTestId('signature-clear-button')).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('calls readSignatureMock when the TouchableOpacity button is pressed', () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(
      <>
        <SignaturePad ref={componentRef} handleSignature={() => {}} />
        {/* TouchableOpacity button that directly calls the ref method */}
        <TouchableOpacity testID="read-signature-btn" onPress={() => componentRef.current?.handleReadSignature()}>
          <Text>Read Signature</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </>,
    );
    const readSignatureBtn = getByTestId('read-signature-btn');
    const signatureScreen = getByTestId('signature-screen');
    const readSignatureMock = signatureScreen.props.readSignature;
    expect(readSignatureMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
    act(() => {
      fireEvent.press(readSignatureBtn);
    });
    expect(readSignatureMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});


